# WKWebView Not Loading URL in NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, webview, wkwebview

XCode MacOS (not iOS) using WKWebView to open a URL in a window with:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSView *webNSView;
@property (assign) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;

- (void)windowDidLoad {
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webNSView.frame];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.webNSView addSubview:webView]; }
```

This is working fine.

I want to send a blank url using [self blankUrl];

I have this:

```
-(void) blankUrl {
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
}
```

But I get error: "Unknown receiver 'webView'; did you mean 'WebView'?"

Changing to WebView gives error: "unrecognized selector sent to class."

Changing to self.webView will compile but doesn't load the url.

Basically, How can I update WKWebView URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `windowDidLoad` you have a local variable called `webView` that you initialize, rather than the property.  Then you try to use the property (uninitialized) one later.

Change the first line of `windowDidLoad` to...

```
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.webNSView.frame];
```

...and also use `self.webView` in `blankUrl`.